# Resizing subviews with AutoLayout

Tags: swift, xcode10.3

I'm setting constraints for a subview within a scroll view and the subview resizes to be ~100 wider than the superview, even when I set leading and trailing constraints

I've tried setting leading and trailing constraints

[Image of my current constraints and the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUYJu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollview  expects it's size from it's children not vice versa , you need to ctrl - drag from the recipes view to main outer view ( Home vc's view ) and select equal widths from the popup